# Ruby: Using this form via JSON, it sometimes creates a lot of entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

When I use a form, updating data with json - it sometimes adds multiple entries. From 3 to 12 at once! I can't see why it's adding so many records at once.

UPDATE:

In the next image, I see a difference between the post. A tiny difference. The first post has a "commit" in the parameters. The second double post, doesn't have a commit.

[image: Example]

My code:

```
#config/routes
post '/employer/proposals/:id' => 'employer/proposals#msg', as: 'employer_comment_on_this_proposal'

#controller
def msg
  @message = ProposalMessage.new(message_params)

  if @message.save
    @messages = @proposal.proposal_messages
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end

#view (haml)
div id='messages'
  = render partial: 'messages', locals: { messages: @messages }

div id='message'
  = render 'msgform'

#partials
- @messages.each do |msg|
  msg.message

#form
= simple_form_for :proposal_messages, url: employer_comment_on_this_proposal_path, remote: true, html: { multipart: true } do |f| 
  = f.text_area :message
  = f.button :submit

#msg.js.erb
$('#messages').html("<%= j (render 'messages') %>");
$('#message').html("<%= j (render 'msgform') %>");
```

How can I get the form to just add 1 record...

Edit: updated code

Edit 2: When I look at the server, I see that the POST action is repeated numerous times.

Comment: why are you using `@message.save` inside `respond_to`

Answer (score 2):

```
def msg   
     @message = ProposalMessage.new(message_params)
    if @message.save    
       @messages = @proposal.proposal_messages                 
       respond_to do |format|
       format.js  
       end 
    end 
  end
```

Comment: When I saw your answer, I though - that must be it. Messages are still entered multiple times. As if the 'submit' button is being hit 5 times...

Comment: @TomWolters kindly update us with the problem , so that we could see that :)

Comment: Sure. I have a page with proposals. On the #show page of said proposal there's a div with messages and below a form to leave a new message.

When I submit a new message, it adds a new message. But sometimes it adds 2, 3 or even more 5, 12... It seems to increase when this happens (not evenly).

When I take a look at the server. I see that the server posts multiple  times. Even with the respond_to block within the msg.save.

Comment: Switched off Turbolinks to prevent multiple bindings. http://lingceng.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/turbolink-best-practice/

Comment: @TomWolters so was that causing problem ?

Comment: It's not solved. Tried unbinding, tried to switch off Turbolinks, I disabled the button.

Comment: I do notice a difference in the console. On post has a "commit" in the parameters. The other one doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Seemed to fix the issue when I add an unbind function to my application.js file.

```
$('#proposalmessage').submit(function() {
  $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
});
```

Comment: After extensive testing, about solution seemed to work after all